# Why is task.started not saved in ViewActivation.prepare?

Tags: django-viewflow

Please look at the following snippet: https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/fa48ec8b129171bceaa25c3ef4a7e6385c30ff6f/viewflow/activation.py#L364

1. I don't understand why `ViewActivation.prepare` does not invoke `self.task.save()` after `self.task.started = now()`.
2. It seems that `self.task.save()` is invoked in other activations after `self.task.started` is set.

Is this a feature or a bug?

Background: I am currently building an analytics tool on top of viewflow for understanding the output performance of my team. I am trying to find out how long my users are spending per task by calculating `task.finished - task.started`.

Answer (score 0):

Viewflow `flow` build from `tasks`, each task type is a separate finite state machine with own set of transitions. There is no restriction on what should happen inside a task activation transition. Task could be saved or not, depends on what logic desired at this place.

`.prepare` calls do not save the task b/c they happen on "HTTP GET" requests, that should be idempotent.

`task.started` tracked over the GET/POST `activation.prepare`/`activation.done` as a hidden form data from {{ activation.management_form }}

Extending task model and corresponding `management_form` would allow you to track any additional task execution information.